# Boneh and Durfee attack on RSA

Tags: rsa, attack

I am a maths teacher and I'm trying to understand the  Boneh and Durfee attack on RSA. I am not very familiar with cryptography. I found a dutch scripting about it.

I know that:

$ e*d\equiv1+k*\phi(n)$

$\phi(n)=n+1-(p+q)$

**I become the function $f(x,y)=xy-(n+1)x-1$, but next I do not understand why you know that $f(k, p+q)\equiv0\,(mod\,e)?$**

Further, they choose modulus $M=e^2$ and choose some polynomials of which we know for sure that $(x,y)=(k,p+q)$ is a root of $f(x,y)\,(mod\,e^2)$.

These polynomials are:

[image]

**How can I see that $(x,y)=(k,p+q)$ is a root of all of these polynomials?**

And then, they go on using a table hat contains the coëfficiënts of the polynomials:

[image]

**I do not understand the meaning of the columns. For example the columns of $g_{0,1}$.**

Comment: Hint for the first question: Assuming $n=pq, \;\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ you get 
$$f(k,p+q)+1+k(p-1)(q-1)=-kn+kpq=k(pq-n)=0,$$
$$f(k,p+q)= -(1+k(p-1)(q-1))=-ed$$

Comment: Hi, Thnx tof the tip. But how do you become: f(k,p+q)+1+k(p−1)(q−1)=−kn+kpq?

Comment: Just expand the two terms
$$f(k,p+q) =k (p + q) - (n + 1) k - 1 =  k p + k q - k n - k - 1$$
$$1+k(p-1)(q-1) =1 + kpq - kp - kq + k$$
Now add the right hand sides and cancel.

Comment: Very sorry, I just made lots of calculations but I still don't understand it. I do not become the answer of my question one. I don't understand the steps: f(k,p+q)+1+k(p−1)(q−1)=−kn+kpq=k(pq−n)=0 and 
f(k,p+q)=−(1+k(p−1)(q−1))=−ed

Comment: Adding the two expanded equations gives:
$$f(k,p+q) +1+k(p-1)(q-1)\\ =  kp + kq - kn - k - 1 + 1 + kpq - kp - kq + k \\=
(kp - kp)  + (kq - kq) - (k - k) - (1 -1) + kpq - kn\\ = k(pq-n) = 0$$
$$f(k,p+q) = - (1+k(p-1)(q-1)) = -(1 +k\phi(n)) = -ed$$
and therefore  $$f(k,p+q) \equiv -ed \equiv 0 \pmod e$$

Comment: Thnx a lot, gammatester. Can you please also help me with the two other questions?

Comment: **Last hint:** For the $g_{l,m},h_{l,m}$ just expand the RHS and read off the coefficients from the powers $x^iy^k,$ e.g.
$$g_{0,1}(x,y) = ef(x,y) = e(xy-(n+1)x-1) = [-e]1-[e(n+1)]x + [e]xy$$
So $-e$ is the coeffcicient of $1,$ $-e(n+1)$ is the coefficient of $x$ and $e$ is the coefficient of $xy$.

Comment: Super! Can you please give me a last hint to find out how to see that (x,y)=(k,p+q) is a root of all of these polynomials? I really took lots of time to figure it out...

Comment: In part 1 we have shown that  $f(k,p+q)$ is a multiple of $e,$ and therefore all the RHS of $g_{l,m}(k, p+q),\;h_{l,m}(k, p+q)$ are multiples of $e^2$.